# Can't click a website button programmatically

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I've tried many ways I just couldn't make this to work
I want to automate login to this website
here is the website http://www.action-manga.com/account/login 
im able to send username and password but I cant click the login button

ive tried WebBrowser and Selenium (both firefox and chrome)

```
        ChromeDriver cd = new ChromeDriver();
        cd.Url = url;
        cd.Navigate();

        IWebElement we = cd.FindElementByName("user-email");
        we.SendKeys("****");
        we = cd.FindElementByName("user-password");
        we.SendKeys("****");

        Thread.Sleep(3000); 

        we = cd.FindElementByClassName("frmSBM button");
        we.Click();

        //these also
        //we = cd.FindElementByName("ws_login");
        //we.Click();

        //((IJavaScriptExecutor)(cd)).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", cd.FindElement(By.Name("ws_login")));

        //((IJavaScriptExecutor)cd).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].trigger('click');", cd.FindElement(By.ClassName("frmSBM button")));
```

and WebBrowser

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.Navigate(url);
        wb.DocumentCompleted += Wb_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    private void Wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
            return;

        if (!is_sec_page)
        {

            //Set username and password strings
            string usernameString = "****";
            string passwordString = "****";

            //Input in to username field
            var x = wb.Document.All.GetElementsByName("user-email");
            x[0].InnerText = usernameString;

            //Input in to password fields
            var y = wb.Document.All.GetElementsByName("user-password");
            y[0].InnerText = passwordString;

            //Click the login button
            var s = wb.Document.All.GetElementsByName("ws_login");
            s[0].InvokeMember("click");
            is_sec_page = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //intract with sec page elements with theire ids and so on
        }
    }
}
```

and many other ways,
here is the markup

```
<div class="form-group frmINP buttons"> <input type="hidden" name="ws_login" value="uLogOct"> <button class="frmSBM button">دخول</button> </div>
```

Comment: Any error to share?

Comment: no error just nothing happened. thanks !

Comment: As I see, that input tag has type=hidden property

Comment: I did search for that found nothing. my knowledge with html and javascript is poor, any solution you suggest? thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with C# but try with button tag's element. Best approach will be locate <input type="submit"> element and fire submit method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

you need find form Id and Submit

changed your code

```
we = cd.FindElementByClassName("frmSBM button");
        we.Click();
```

correct

```
we = cd.FindElementById("loginform");
            we.Submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
we = cd.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="loginform"]/fieldset[1]/div[3]/button"))
we.click()
```

Steps:

- Inspect element
- Rt click -> copy->copy xpath (or any way you want i.e by selector and so on..)